# Retrofit http Cache-control check send back Cache even if stale and make network call again

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, cache-control

I am using Retrofit 1.9.+ and okhttp:2.2.+.

I would like to cache my responses. I did it with Okclient interceptors as follows:

```
public abstract class RestController {
private static Context mContext;
private static long SIZE_OF_CACHE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB

public static RestAdapter mRestAdapter;

public static void init(final Context context, String baseAPIUrl) {
    mContext = context;

    // Create Cache
    Cache cache = null;
    try {
        cache = new Cache(new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "http"), SIZE_OF_CACHE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(RestController.class.getSimpleName(), "Could not create Cache!", e);
    }

    // Create OkHttpClient
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Add Cache-Control Interceptor
    okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(mCacheControlInterceptor);

    // Create Executor
    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(baseAPIUrl)
            .setExecutors(executor, executor)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
}

private static final Interceptor mCacheControlInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        // Add Cache Control only for GET methods
        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                // 1 day
                request.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached")
                        .build();
            } else {
                // 4 weeks stale
                request.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-stale=2419200")
                        .build();
            }
        }

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        // Re-write response CC header to force use of cache
        return response.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=86400") // 1 day
                .build();
    }
};

public static Boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo == null) {
        return false;
    }
    NetworkInfo.State network = networkInfo.getState();
    return (network == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || network == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING);
}
```

}

Now I need to implement a logic in giving back cache. My cache needs to have two metrics: 
1 fresh_upto 
2 Throw away

Then logic is like 
    `if(cache is present and current time <live upto){
send back cache
}
else if(current time<throwawaytime and current time >live upto){
send back cache
make another network call
onresponse send the new data back
}`

how can i achieve this with cache control. can I use max-age or max-stale for this?

Comment: Hello, is your problem solved? I need similar kind of solution

Comment: @MayuriRuparel Sorry, but I have implemented SQLite caching for my responses to achieve this.. I am not sure, if it is possible with Retrofit..

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for retrofit it is working in my project

`@Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=" + (MINUTE))
 @GET("your Url")
 Call<ResponseBody> getCourseStructureFromCache("Your Request paramater and all");`